# Python 3 Stripping complicated String

Tags: python, string, strip

my python string looks like this:

```
a = '\n\nSITE TYPE:\xa0VOLUNTARY CLEANUP\xa0\xa0\nNATIONAL PRIORITIES LIST:\xa0NO\xa0\xa0\nACRES:\xa048 ACRES\xa0\xa0\nAPN:\xa011518019\xa0\xa0\n\n\n\nCLEANUP OVERSIGHT AGENCIES:\nDEL NORTE COUNTYDTSC - SITE CLEANUP PROGRAM -  LEAD AGENCYUS EPA\n\n\n\n\n'
```

unable to use simple strip, if i do a.strip('\n') only the left of strip is removed and if i strip or rstrip it doesnt remove, moreover is there a different way to remove the unicode characters and newline character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.replace` to replace all newline chars `"\n"`. And use `str.decode` with `'latin1'` as encoding to decode the string.

**Ex:**

```
a = '\n\nSITE TYPE:\xa0VOLUNTARY CLEANUP\xa0\xa0\nNATIONAL PRIORITIES LIST:\xa0NO\xa0\xa0\nACRES:\xa048 ACRES\xa0\xa0\nAPN:\xa011518019\xa0\xa0\n\n\n\nCLEANUP OVERSIGHT AGENCIES:\nDEL NORTE COUNTYDTSC - SITE CLEANUP PROGRAM -  LEAD AGENCYUS EPA\n\n\n\n\n'
a = a.replace("\n", "")
print(a.decode('latin1'))
```

**Output:**

```
SITE TYPE: VOLUNTARY CLEANUP  NATIONAL PRIORITIES LIST: NO  ACRES: 48 ACRES  APN: 11518019  CLEANUP OVERSIGHT AGENCIES:DEL NORTE COUNTYDTSC - SITE CLEANUP PROGRAM -  LEAD AGENCYUS EPA
```

**Note:** Tested in python2.7

Comment: thank you, it works, but how i can identify the unicode to decode.